# Unable to install python-fingerprint module o Raspberry Pi OS

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, raspberry-pi, fingerprint

I am trying to install python-fingerprint module on Raspberry Pi OS.previously I installed same on raspbian os.It works with same command **sudo apt-get install python-fingerprint**

But now it failed with dependencies python-serial and python-pil check attached screenshot for referrence. please guide[image]

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understand the different "Raspberry Pi OS.previously I installed same on raspbian os" OS you are referring too.
Debian version
7   Wheezy
8   Jessie
9   Stretch
10  Buster
11  Bullseye (latest)

Have you tried to fix the broken links with:  *sudo apt --fix-missing update*

Answer (score 0):

for raspberry pi OS (bullseye) ,use command as
**sudo apt-get install python3-fingerprint**

it works....